# collection equality using hamcrest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I want to assert equality of two collection using hamcrest.

I know there is `contains` matcher but I want it to ignore ordering.

{1,2} is equals to {2,1} for my need.

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `containsInAnyOrder()` :

```
  List colors = Arrays.asList("red","green","blue");
  assertThat(colors, containsInAnyOrder("green", "red", "blue")); // is true
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Collection col1, col2;
Set set1 = new HashSet(col1);
set1.removeAll(col2);
assertTrue(set1.isEmpty());
```

Also you can create utils class like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Setoperationsunionintersectiondifferencesymmetricdifferenceissubsetissuperset.htm) and use it to find difference